# Unchecking Delete not working

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level

I created a new permissions level called AEV.  Only able to Add, Edit, View a list item.  But, not allowed to delete (unchecked).
However, when I gave a group the AEV permissions, they're still able to delete. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check permissions by clicking on the "Check permissions" button on site permissions and list permissions settings.

It looks like members of the group also have membership in another groups with higher permission level.

Comment: Hey @raf, you answered my other question which is loosely based on this one.  So I'll close this as answered.  Thanks!.